# neural network c++ code from matlab coder

Tags: c++, matlab, arduino, neural-network, matlab-compiler

I trained a neural network in the Matlab "Neural Net Pattern Recognition" toolbox and generated a .m function from the toolbox. I also wrote my own function, which gets a dataset containing a inf x 5 matrix with datapoints as input, calls the NN function from the toolbox and returns a vector with the recognized pattern and a percent value. (the input matrix contains the pattern, which should be detected)

Because I need to run the code on an Arduino, I tried to use the Matlab Coder to generate C++ Code but it doesn't work. First, I get the warning that arrayfun is not supported for code generation (the call os arrayfun is in the generated function from the toolbox). After that, I defined the input of the function as " double(:7351 x 5)" (it's up to 7351 because my dataset for training is that big).
Now the coder builds an MEX file for checking for run-time issues and there some errors occur.

I don't know why the target build log is in german because the rest of Matlab is in English but in generally some brackets and semicolons are missing but why? How can brackets be missing in the matrix.h or amlrt.h???

```
  1   cl  /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE   /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG  /fp:strict  /I "C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\simulink\include" /I "C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\shared\simtargets" /I "C:\Users\Kai\Desktop\YUN_SI~1" /I "C:\Users\Kai\Desktop\YUN_SI~1\codegen\mex\NeuralNetwork" /I ".\interface" /I "C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include" /I "." "NeuralNetwork_data.c"
    2   NeuralNetwork_data.c
    3   c:\program files\matlab\r2016a\extern\include\matrix.h(260) : error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'mxChar'
    4   c:\program files\matlab\r2016a\extern\include\matrix.h(260) : error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ';'
    5   c:\program files\matlab\r2016a\extern\include\matrix.h(605) : error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt '{' vor '*'
    6   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(56) : error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ')' vor '*'
    7   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(56) : error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt '{' vor '*'
    8   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(56) : error C2373: 'emlrtCTX': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Modifizierer
    9           C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(50): Siehe Deklaration von 'emlrtCTX'
   10   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(56) : error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'aTLS'
   11   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(56) : error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ')'
   12   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(133) : error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'EmlrtErrorFunction'
   13   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(139) : error C2059: Syntaxfehler: '}'
   14   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(194) : error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'emlrtContextGlobal'
   15   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(194) : error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ';'
   16   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(808) : error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ')' vor '*'
   17   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(808) : error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt '{' vor '*'
   18   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include\emlrt.h(808) : error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ')'
   19   c:\users\kai\desktop\yun_simulink\codegen\mex\neuralnetwork\NeuralNetwork_data.h(32) : error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'emlrtContextGlobal'
   20   c:\users\kai\desktop\yun_simulink\codegen\mex\neuralnetwork\NeuralNetwork_data.h(32) : error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ';'
   21   NeuralNetwork_data.c(22) : error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'emlrtContextGlobal'
   22   NeuralNetwork_data.c(22) : error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ';'
   23   NeuralNetwork_data.c(22) : error C2513: '/*global*/ ': Keine Variable vor '=' deklariert
   24   gmake: *** [NeuralNetwork_data.obj] Error 2
```

In general, it is possible to create C++ code from the NN toolbox but why doesn't it work in my case?

The function I want to translate in c++ is:

```
function [ activity, percent ] = NeuralNetwork( Data )
%NN for recogniton of activitys standing, sitting, walking from Accelerometer data, relative error
%is returned in percent
%   input Data contains 5 columns. 1. col -> time; 2-4.col ->
%   x,y,z-Acceleration; 5.col -> activity
%   VAR activity contains 1 for walking, 2 for sitting and 3 for standing 


    Acceleration_data = Data(:,2:4);  %store acceleration data in a matrix
    Acceleration_data = Acceleration_data';     %NN input expects transposed matrix

    targets = Data(:,5);    %activity that should be detected from the NN
    targets = targets';     %output of NN is also transposed

    NNfit = myNeuralNetworkFunction(Acceleration_data); %call the trained NN 
    NNfit = round(NNfit);                             %output can be e.g. 0.998 -> round to 1
    activity=zeros(1,length(NNfit));                   %allocate memory for cpp-code


for i=1:length(NNfit)               %NNfit is a 3D matrix, after round one
    [val pos] = max(NNfit(:,i));    %element is 1 the other are 0 the number of 
                                    %the row represents the activity
    activity(i) = pos;              %vektor containing the activity
end

cnt=0;              %calc percent of correct recognized data points
for i=1:length(NNfit)
   if activity(i) == targets(i)
       cnt = cnt+1;         %amound of correct recognized data points
   end
end

percent = (cnt/length(targets))*100;   %calc percent

end
```

edit:

The file NeuralNetwork_data.c:

```
/* Include files */
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include "NeuralNetwork.h"
#include "NeuralNetwork_data.h"
#include "blas.h"

/* Variable Definitions */
emlrtCTX emlrtRootTLSGlobal = NULL;
const volatile char_T *emlrtBreakCheckR2012bFlagVar = NULL;
covrtInstance emlrtCoverageInstance;
emlrtContext emlrtContextGlobal = { true, false, 131434U, NULL, "NeuralNetwork",
  NULL, false, { 2045744189U, 2170104910U, 2743257031U, 4284093946U }, NULL };

emlrtRSInfo f_emlrtRSI = { 68, "eml_mtimes_helper",
  "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016a\\toolbox\\eml\\lib\\matlab\\ops\\eml_mtimes_helper.m"
};

emlrtRSInfo g_emlrtRSI = { 85, "xgemm",
  "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016a\\toolbox\\eml\\eml\\+coder\\+internal\\+blas\\xgemm.m"
};

emlrtRSInfo n_emlrtRSI = { 214, "minOrMax",
  "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016a\\toolbox\\eml\\eml\\+coder\\+internal\\minOrMax.m"
};

emlrtRSInfo o_emlrtRSI = { 375, "minOrMax",
  "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016a\\toolbox\\eml\\eml\\+coder\\+internal\\minOrMax.m"
};

emlrtRSInfo p_emlrtRSI = { 347, "minOrMax",
  "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016a\\toolbox\\eml\\eml\\+coder\\+internal\\minOrMax.m"
};

/* End of code generation (NeuralNetwork_data.c) */
```

Comment: Off topic: [see if octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is available for your arduino and will execute your .m files. May save you some effort.

Comment: Any way we could get a look at `NeuralNetwork_data.c`?

Comment: I edited the content of NeuralNetwork_data.c. Is octave a program like matlab or is it possible to let it run on the arduino? @user4581301

Comment: Octave is an opensource tool similar to matlab and manages execute a large number of m files without modification. The language choice was not matlab's; it looks like your copy of Visual Studio is German. matrix.h seems to be missing the include that would pull in `mxChar`. Possible causes for this are extremely broad and may be causing the following errors. I'm still on matlab 2008, so I can't help much digging upward through the includes..

Comment: A few days ago I created c++ code from the same function (I only did minor changes like preallocation of NNfit) and the coder worked (I couldn't use that code because mex.h and some #includes were missing). What might be the problem of the coder? My function, the settings or my installation? Are there any things I can try to make it run? Is it possible to generate c++ code in octave? Maybe I will try that tomorrow but I would prefer matlab.

Comment: I've only used octave to knock out quick prototypes on embedded hardware. In one case it actually met the performance targets so it stayed. I've never used it to generate code. Matlab to C I have very little experience with--once and I wound up having to re-write it in C anyway.

Comment: Can you try generating code for a simple MATLAB function with one line code with MATLAB coder to narrow down the problem?

Comment: I created another NN with the matlab example dataset "Iris Flowers" and a script, which is just calling the function from the NN toolbox and the coder worked with it (I didn't test the Cpp-Code!). The Problem must be in my function "NeuralNetwork" I think, but I have no idea which part it can be?

Comment: edit: I also tested only the NN function from the toolbox for my problem and it worked, too. Si it's definetly a problem with the other self written function, which calls my Neural Network.

Comment: What is the right build type, if I want to use the code on an aduino? Static library or Source code?